# How to get firstInstallTime in Android Using Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin forms. I am developing an application. In that I need to find the app installed date programatically for Android.

Anyone of you please respond.

Comment: Personally I use this  https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Settings plugin by James Montemagno and create a property named IsFirstTime which will be set to true when loaded the app for first time. That's when you can record the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Get Date and Time of First Install**

In Android you can use this code for retrieve Date and Time of first install:

```
long installDateTime = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.xxxx.yyyy", 0).firstInstallTime;
```

> Params of getPackageInfo method
>
> - *packageName* (String): The full name (i.e. com.google.apps.contacts) of the desired package.
> - *flags* (int): Additional option flags to modify the data returned.
>
> Return
>
> - PackageInfo (that contains *firstInstallTime* field)
>
> Method used for retrieve info about installed package.
>
> More info on [Android Dev](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo(java.lang.String,%20int))

On Xamarin.Forms we can retrieve package in a similar way.

```
var datetimelong = context.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo("com.xxxx.yyyy", 0).FirstInstallTime;
```

> Params of GetPackageInfo method
>
> - *packageName* (String): The full name (i.e. com.google.apps.contacts) of the desired package.
> - *flags* (enum): Additional option flags to modify the data returned.
>
> Return
>
> - PackageInfo (that contains *FirstInstallTime* field)
>
> Method used for retrieve info about installed package.
>
> More info on [Xamarin Dev](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Content.PM.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo/p/System.String/Android.Content.PM.PackageInfoFlags/)

**Hint**: FirstInstallTime field return the install time in "Unix time".
Convert Example:

```
var datetime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var firstinstall = datetime.AddMilliseconds(ValueOfFirstInstallTime);
```

As you can see, the paths are very similar, because Xamarin refers to native Android libraries. (I think that 'Binding' is the correct name of technique used)
This means that most of the basic features available in Java for Android are also available in Xamarin with a similar patterns.

> *Pay attention*
>   This date will reset whenever the app is uninstalled and reinstalled.

There is no way to know if it is the first time that a user has installed your app.
Maybe you can use a workaround like online db where save the first date and time of installation associated with an user id or similar.

I hope I was clear, sorry for my english.
Byee.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response SteeBono.It Worked for me

Comment: It's a pleasure

Comment: Isn't FirstInstallTime expressed in milliseconds?

Comment: If I remember correctly, firstInstallTime is in milliseconds based on unix time.

This time units are as per JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis.
And this returns the current time in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.

Check this out:
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis/

Comment: @Gusman I have edited my answer. From datetime.AddSeconds to datetime.AddMilliseconds.

Byee.